# Apache Storm Supervisor not Running the Bolt

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, apache-storm, real-time-data

I have created a storm cluster over Amazon EC2 instances. I tested my code in local Environment (pseudo-distributed environment) and it worked fine. But the code doesn't seems to work when I run the code in distributed environment. **Is there something technical I am missing here, while setting up the cluster**.

I can make a statement that the supervisor nodes are not running the bolts, as I checked the **CPU usage** of all the supervisor nodes and none of them was going above 1% but the master(nimbus) was running at 100% every time until the code execution finished.

I also checked the Java processes running in supervisor nodes and **"jps"** doesn't show my topology.

Note: The cluster shows 2 supervisors in the UI running over nimbus. That shows that the cluster is setup in distributed environment.

Comment: what's the log saying .. might be usefull if provide them here

Comment: I solved my problem and added my solution here.

Comment: You should add your solution as an answer and accept your own answer ;)

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax Thanks for the suggestion. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution to my Problem:**

Previously I was running Using the `LocalCluster` instead of `StormSubmitter`

Use this:

```
StormSubmitter.submitTopologyWithProgressBar(args[0], conf, builder.createTopology());
```

instead of:

```
LocalCluster cluster = new LocalCluster();
cluster.submitTopology("test", conf, builder.createTopology());
Utils.sleep(10000);
cluster.killTopology("test");
cluster.shutdown();
```